# Spot colors in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

in mpdf (I use 8.1.4 with PHP 8.2) I can add spot color by code like this

`$mpdf->AddSpotColor('Thru-cut', 10, 10, 10, 10); //name, c, m, y, k`

But after that I can't see this spot colors ex. in Adobe Illustrator (it should appear in Swatches (Window -> Swatches)).

I checked and it's not a problem that mpdf generate pdf in version 1.4
`%PDF-1.4`.
I mean other pdf's 1.4 generated from other programms works in AI.

I tried override ColorWritter writeSpotColors() with code from pdf but it still doesn't work. Has someone got similar problem, or maybe have solution?

Comment: When Adobe Illustrator saves a PDF using the default settings, it stores swatches in XMP meta data, specifically the `xmpTPg:SwatchGroups` group. If you save a PDF from Illustrator without "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities" you'll see the swatches also disappear from the panel, although the color still exists in the document (if used). mPDF does have an `SetAdditionalXmpRdf` method, however not matter what I put in there, even if I copy directly from a PDF with recognized swatches, I cannot make Illustrator recognize the swatches from mPDF, so there's something else, too.

Comment: Yes, I saw this Illustrator "XML" but...
When I've got file generated by Corel it's pdf 1.7 then AI see this swatches. 
Even if I convert this Corel pdf 1.7 file to pdf 1.4 via https://docupub.com/pdfconvert/ AI still see this swatches. 
Corel does not incluse ```xmpTPg``` into pdf as same as this online converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

I found the answer and it's simple.

If you defined spot color via mpdf

`$mpdf->AddSpotColor('WHITE', 0, 66, 30, 13);`

Then you need to use it in code example to fill svg:

`<path fill="spot(WHITE, 100%)" ...`

This code snippet I found later can be usefull: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/development/example55_new_mPDF_v5-1_color_and_other_features.php